# The following query is only being outputted in the first console.log and is undefined in the second

Tags: javascript, sqlite, hash

```
let salt;
    db.all(
      `SELECT salt FROM users WHERE username = ?`, [username],
      (err, row) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        salt = row[0].salt;
        console.log(' SALT: ' + salt + 'saltEND');
      }
    )
    console.log(' SALT: ' + salt + 'saltEND2');
```

The correct row information is being outputted in `console.log(' SALT: ' + salt + 'saltEND');` but not in saltEND2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @BHughes `db.all()` is asynchronous function which means it takes some time while the synchronous functions run, so your "saltEND2" log logs the current value of `salt` which is `undefined`

Comment: @Aleksandar Oh that makes sense! any suggestions, maybe a timeout function?